# Fluent Validation Filter Arguments For collectionValidator

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to filter arguments to use in a collection validator using FluentValidations:

I have a generic Class for Collections which looks like:

```
public class ItemCollection<TEntity>
{
    public ItemCollection(TEntity[] items);
    public TEntity[] Items { get; }
}
```

I have a Validator for my ItemCollection which looks like so:

```
public FooCollectionValidator:  AbstractValidator<ItemCollection<Foo>>
{

    public FooCollectionValidator(IDictionary<string, FooMetadata> allowedMetadata)
    {
        //Setting Rules using Must works fine
        this.RuleForEach(x => x.Items).Must(x => allowedMetadata.ContainsKey(x.Key));
    }
}
```

I Need to set a Validator For each on of the Item but I would like to filter my Metadata For the Child Validator No matter what way I try I don't have access to the items to be able to filter:

```
this.RuleForEach(x => x.Items).SetValidator(x =>
{            
    //I want to filter the metadata by the Key and pass it to the child validator
    var metadata = allowedMetadata[x.Key];
    return new FooDTOValidator(metadata )       
});
```

This Doesn't work because X always refers to the collection and not the individual item.  How can I filter arguments passed to a collection validator?

Comment: Did you tried this.RuleFor(x => x.Items).SetCollectionValidator(...) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fumbled a bit around and it does not seem possible with `SetValidator`. `SetCollectionValidator` as suggested is or will be deprecated.
The only way I can think of is this:

```
this.RuleForEach(x => x.Items).Must(x =>
  {
      var validator = new FooDTOValidator(allowedMetadata[x.Key]);
      return validator.Validate(x).IsValid;
  });
```

**Edit**
As noted in the comment we loose our error messages. There might be a chance to preserve them. Take this as not tested but according to the [docs](https://fluentvalidation.net/start#root-context-data) we can get the *Root Context Data* and add our failures if any.

```
this.RuleForEach(x => x.Items).Custom((x, context) =>
{
    var validator = new FooDTOValidator(allowedMetadata[x.Key]);
    var result = validator.Validate(x);
    if (!result.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var failure in result.Errors)
        {
            context.AddFailure(failure);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I wouldn’t bother creating the overhead for an adapter if I’m just going to be throwing away the validation messages.  But I ended up sticking with rule for each so I’ll give you the check

Comment: @johnny5 you're right. We loose our error messages. Perhaps the code in the edit is worth a try. I have not tested it and am curious if this works.